# when i try to save this file it creates and folder for the entire path

Tags: asp.net

```
ZipFileToCreate = "c:\user\desktop\webservice\file.zip";
```

So, when i try to save this file it creates the folder for the path like user\desktop\webservice\file\

Why is it so?

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(ZipFileToCreate, FileMode.Open);
byte[] data = new Byte[fs.Length];
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
br.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
br.Close();
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/x-zip-compressed";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + Parameter + ".zip");
DeleteOldFiles();
Response.BinaryWrite(data);
```

Comment: What value does `Parameter` have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to be using the `Environment.GetFolderPath` method to find the current users' Desktop folder rather than hard-coding "c:\user\desktop\webservice\file.zip". Also using `Path.Combine` to build a path is more reliable than string concatenation. Try

```
Parameter = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "file.zip");
```